# How can I get Microsoft Dynamics 365 to appear in the list of data sources when creating a report in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio, report, dynamics-crm, fetchxml, dynamics-365

[vs studio data source list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUCMV.png)

I have VS 15 installed but it started crashing after I installed BIDS.

I know VS 17 may not be compatible with BIDS but is there a workaround because I am unable to find download links for VS 13 or older.

I have the following tools installed:

SQL Server Data Tools

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt

SQL Server Reporting Services

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/create-deploy-and-manage-mobile-and-paginated-reports

Microsoft Dynamics CRM Report Authoring Extension

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh699675.aspx

Thanks

Comment: You are using VS 2017 but you have linked the SSDT addin for VS 2015. Are you sure SSDT works with VS 2017 (I am pretty sure not since my question is still at the top of the comments :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment VS 2017 is not supported. Here is quote from Dynamics 365 Report Authoring extension [software requirements](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh699754.aspx#report_ext_gen_req):

> Microsoft Visual Studio 2015, Microsoft Visual Studio 2013, Microsoft Visual Studio 2012, or Microsoft Visual Studio 2010.

So the only way out for you is to install VS 2015/2013/2012/2010. Good luck.

Comment: I have 2015 installed but it started crashing after I installed BIDS. Suggestions?

Comment: Re-Install VS 2015 using the repair option then it should work